# Pure Phase Number

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, quantum-mechanics

I am read a solution (4.9) [Here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~jeanbel/4782/problem207.pdf) say:

> ... both $a, d$ are pure phases, so that it is always possible to ﬁnd (non unique) real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \delta$ such that $a = e^{i(\alpha−\beta/2−\delta/2)}$...

My question: What is a pure phases? Why $a, d$ are pure phase?. Why it is always possible to ﬁnd (non unique) real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \delta$ such that $a = e^{i(\alpha−\beta/2−\delta/2)}$?

> ...Therefore it is possible to assume that none of the cœﬃcients $a, b, c, d$ vanish. In particular, there are real numbers $0 < γ, γ^{'} < \pi$ such that $|a| = \cos γ/2$

Why the module of any Complex number can be represented than $\sin$ or $\cos$ functions?

Comment: I would understand a "pure phase" to be a complex number of absolute value 1.  So it has the form $e^{i\phi}$ for some angle $\phi$.

Comment: all complex number can be represent in the form $e^\phi$?

Comment: I mean real angles.

Comment: @juaninf All complex numbers can be represented as $ae^{ib}$ for real $a$ and $b$: this is the [polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_form#Polar_form) of a complex number. The ones with $a=1$ form the unit circle in the complex plane.